# Ajax not working in JQuery-1.7.1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to call method of CI through ajax but method is not called.I am trying to solve this issue since 2 days but can't get any solution.Below is my snippet

```
function list_payment_details()
{  
    var pagee = page;
    if (pagee == '0')
    {
        var pagee = '1';
    }

    var user_name = $('#search_user').val();
    var device_type = $('#device_type').val();
    var category_name = $('#filter_category_name').val();
    var subcategory_name = $('#filter_subcategory_name').val();
    var url_payment = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/advertisepayment/advertise_payment_list';
    alert(pagee + user_name + device_type + category_name + subcategory_name + sort_field + sort_type);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            pagee: pagee,
            user_name: user_name,
            device_type: device_type,
            category_name: category_name,
            subcategory_name: subcategory_name,
            sort_field: sort_field,
            sort_type: sort_type
        },
         //dataType: 'json',
        url: url_payment,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so... who calls this method? whats the errormessage? why the preventdefault? whats the context? What have you tried so far? I am sorry to be the one telling you this, but we can't do wizardry here. We need information to help you.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you receive no data on your backend?

Comment: what error it shows in console?

Comment: When do you call "list_payment_details()" and what do you get as error? Can we see the script in your "url" to see what you do with the data? Try to add ", error: function(x, e, t) {console.log(x.responseText);}"  in your Ajax call to see what you get when it doesn't works

Comment: check your URL it seems the target url is not correct...

Comment: when i add error property like as below :                                                              error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus + " error " + errorThrown));
    },                                                                                                              it prints "error error"

Answer (score 0):

in order for ajax call to be executed it needs a target url, in your case url: url_payment. $.post(URL,data,callback);
check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

In your question last line is commented ("//" at the begining of the line). if is the same in your script, that line is ignored, so your ajax will not be executetd.

Basically you provide the ajax type, the data to be sent but you don't provide url, data type, etc beacause they are commented.

Answer (score 0):

**insert**

'

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log(textStatus + " error " + errorThrown)
}
```

'

**for trace  error**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            pagee: pagee,
            user_name: user_name,
            device_type: device_type,
            category_name: category_name,
            subcategory_name: subcategory_name,
            sort_field: sort_field,
            sort_type: sort_type
        },
         //dataType: 'json',
        url: url_payment,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
      ,error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus + " error " + errorThrown)
    }
    });
```

**IF  URL  correct**

Comment: when i add error property like as below :                                                  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus + " error " + errorThrown)); },                                       it prints "error error"

Comment: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0):

Can use Chrome for debug  press F12 
and go to Network tap look **Status Code**  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAlOh.png)